# RxJS multiple subscriptions in Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs

Apologies if this is a duplicate questions, but I am new to RxJS and Angular, and I wasn't quite sure what to search.

I have the following Angular component which has 2 nested components:

```
<div>
    <h1>Parent Container</h1>

    <nest-one></nest-one>
    <nest-two></nest-two>
</div>
```

Each of those nested components can call the method on my service, which executes a http call:

```
getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product[]>  {
    return this.http.get('product/' + id)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And both nested components subscribe to this method call like so:

```
this.productService.getProduct(id)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.product = data;
    }
  );
```

My questions is, how can I, or is it possible to call the method `getProduct` in my `productService` and for both nested components' subscription to be executed, regardless of which component I call it from?

This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. Another option could be to have a base class and use that instead, but I want to see if this is possible or not.

Comment: If you subscribe in both components it gets executed twice, so where's the problem? You want  to call it just once?

Comment: @martin yes, I want both subscriptions to be executed each time the method is called (from anywhere)...that's not currently happening for me but are you saying it should be?

Comment: Yes, if you make two subscriptions to `getProduct` you'll make two requests

Comment: @martin my subscriptions are never being executed if I simply call `this.productService.getProduct(id)` on it's own.

Comment: You have to subscribe at the end of the chain. `this.productService.getProduct(id).subscribe(...)`

Comment: @martin but I only need to do that once right, in my `ngOnInit` for example, then every time I call `this.productService.getProduct(id)`, my subscription should execute right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your parent container to handle this.
Add an output to both components for when you want to load a new product an one input to pass the retrieved product down to them.

parent.ts

```
loadProduct$ = new Subject<string>();
product$ = this.loadProduct$.switchMap(id => this.productService.getProduct(id)).share();
```

parent.html

```
<div>
      <h1>Parent Container</h1>

      <nest-one [product]="product$ | async"  (loadProduct)="loadProduct$.next($event)></nest-one>
      <nest-two [product]="product$ | async"  (loadProduct)="loadProduct$.next($event) ></nest-two>

  </div>
```

Now both children are getting the new product regardless of which  initiated the call. The share operator makes sure that there are no multiple streams and the backend is only called once. This is one way to do it - if you describe your use case more detailed, we may give you better answers.

Comment: This is route I took in the end. I just wasn't sure if there was an easier way to do this like some sort of state manage such as Redux. Anyways, why do you have `loadProduct$.next($event)` instead of just calling the `loadProduct$` method and setting the `product$` variable?

Comment: If I would reset (=change reference of) the product-observable, the async pipe would have to resubscribe to the source as it has changed for it. If I do it like above, no references are changed and there only ever will be one stream